# Can't access the value of state with React Router Link component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to pass a poster image from Component A to component B.  I have searched many different examples but nothing works.  I am using react-router v4 and Link to do this.  I setup my Component A as follows using Cloudinary React API to load thumb images.

```
class Topics extends Component {
 state = {
  topics: [
   {id: 1, text:'Learning', thumb:'Learning', poster: '../static/street.jpg'}, 
   {id: 2, text:'Healthy Living', thumb:'Healthy', poster: '../static/healthy-crop.jpg'}, 
   {id: 3, text: 'Mentorship', thumb:'Mentor'}, 
   {id: 4, text: 'Community', thumb: 'Neighbour'}, 
   {id: 5, text: 'Economic Dev', thumb: 'open'}, 
   {id: 6, text: 'Urban Parks', thumb:'Park'}
  ]
 };

 render() {
  const { topics } = this.state;
  return (
   <section>
    <CloudinaryContext cloudName='dxanqdr7i'>
      <PageTitle>Topics</PageTitle>
      <h2>Choose a topic from below to learn more</h2>
      <div>
        {topics.map((topic, index) => (
          <div key={index}>                
            <Link 
              key={topics.id} 
              to={{
                pathname: `/${topic.text}`,
                state: {
                  poster: topic.poster
                }
              }}>
              {topic.text}
            </Link>
            <Image key={topic}  publicId={topic.thumb} 
              dpr="auto"
              responsive
              width='auto'
              crop="scale">
            </Image>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </CloudinaryContext>
   </section>
  );
 }
}
```

My component B receives the props.  If I `console.log(this.props.location.state);` the poster image is returned in the console.  If I add `this.props.location.state.poster` then I get an error: `TypeError: cannot read property 'poster' of undefined` . He is my Component B.

```
class Topic extends Component{
 render() {
  const { poster } = this.props.location.state;
  return (
   <React.Fragment>
    <div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${poster})`}}>
      <h1>{this.props.match.params.topicId}</h1>
    </div>
   </React.Fragment>
  );
 }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: are you navigating through link or through url

Comment: Don't you need to define a `constructor()` to initialize state ?
See [example](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class)

Comment: I am navigating through link as far as I am aware of

Comment: @dashboard I thought you didn't have to use constructor anymore.  I followed a tyler mcginnis course and he didn't use `constructor()` but I will try.

Comment: Maybe it remains undefined for a little time. Then you can use **conditional rendering operator** like 
`!this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.poster`

Comment: @dashboard the conditional rendering doesn't seem to work

Comment: dashboard is correct, there is an initial render occurring before the props are filled from the parent component. Either render conditionally as noted above or specify an alternative value. e.g. `const poster = this.props.location.state.poster || null` if you ALWAYS end up with null, then add `componentDidUpdate` and console log your `this.props` to be sure you're not losing that value somehow

Comment: Just a side note, its not necessary wrap your div in a `React.Fragment` when you're not stacking them.

Comment: @JoshuaUnderwood I think that was it.  Should I put `this.props.location.state.poster || null` into a 'componentDidMount`?

Comment: I once dealt with this exact problem. The problem is in `Topics` component where you call `<Link 
              key={topics.id} 
              to={{
                pathname: \`/${topic.text}\`,
                state: {
                  poster: topic.poster
                }
              }}>`  Do not pass `location.state` like this. Instead append the parameter as a prop to your `Topic` component using `<Route />` component.

Comment: @dashboard could you give an example of how you would do that.  I am not sure I am following 100% with the `Topic` part

Comment: Thanks to @dashboard

Comment: @dashboard how would you append `location.state` as a parameter to my `Topic` `<Route/>` component?  I am not clear on this.  Any chance on an example of this?

Comment: You don't pass the location state as parameter, it automatically does. But with react-router-4 you don't need that approach. When you use your `<Topic />` component inside route like `<Route render={(props) => <Topic poster={this.state.topic.poster} {...props} />}/>` that way you pass parameters as props which is the right way. Of course I presumed that you have your `topic.poster` in your state. And inside your `<Topic />` component you can access the prop with `this.props.poster` .